# Slick 3.0 transactions in Play 2.4

Tags: scala, transactions, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I have a controller that makes various calls to database model classes that perform various operations on a PostgreSQL database. I want to perform all of these operations inside a single transaction. In Play 2.3 I was able to wrap code in `DB.withTransaction { ... }` to get it to perform all actions inside a single transaction.

With Play 2.4 and Slick 3.0 it appears that Slick handles connection management, and `DB.withTransaction` no longer seems the correct way to handle this (it throws `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "Could not find database for default" anyway). What's the proper way to group Slick operations inside a transaction from within the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of your problem is [DBIO composition](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/dbio.html#transactions-and-pinned-sessions).

Firstly, all your atomic operations should be implemented by a `DBIOAction` (A `DBIOAction` represents an operation which will be executed on the DB).

Next, you can compose all your DBIOAction together, with `andThen`, `flatMap`, or using a `for comprehension` (see [DBIOAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction) api)

When you have your composed DBIO, you can call `.transactionally` to make the DBIOAction transactional when it will be executed on a db.

Sample:

```
def updateUsername(id: Long, username: String) = Schemas.users.filter(_.id === id).map(_.username).update(username)
def updateUserAddress(id: Long, address: String) = Schemas.addresses.filter(_.id === id).map(_.address).update(address)
def getUser(id: Long) = Schemas.users.filter(_.id === id).head

val operations = for {
   _ <- updateUserName(1, "foo")
   _ <- updateUserAddress(1, "bar")
   user <- getUser(1)
} yield user

db.run(operations.transactionally)
```

The way to obtain the `db` object is explained in the Play documentation.